# -Ofast produces incorrect code while using long double

Tags: c++, c, compilation, g++, compiler-optimization

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main(void)
{
    int val = 500;
    printf("%d\n", (int)((long double)val / 500));
    printf("%d\n", (int)((long double)500 / 500));
}
```

Obviously it should output `1 1`. But if you compile it with `-Ofast`, it will output `0 1`, why?

And if you change `500` to other values (such as `400`) and compile with `-Ofast`, it will still output `1 1`.

Compiler explorer with `-Ofast`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YkX7fB

It seems this line causes the problem.

[image]

Comment: Changing `val` to less than 500 gives 0. But I'm not sure of your assumption that `(int)(500./500)` is obviously 1.

Comment: In the first one, perhaps the fast optimisation caused the compiler to generate code that multiplies by `0.001999999999` instead of the division. In the second one it may not be computed at runtime at all.

Comment: @cigien This is not the point. The point is both `printf` statement should output the same value because they are essentially `(int)(500./500)`.

Comment: The do not *have to* output the same value. In the second one, the compiler is allowed to generate `puts("1");`

Comment: @Ghastlcon Essentially the same does not mean the same. Note that you get `1` if `val` is `const` or `constexpr`. The difference might come down to whether the evaluation is done at compile time or run time.

Comment: Only a guess, but I think the compiler with `-ffast-math` enabled can calculate `/500` as `*(1.0/500)`. If this value is rounded down, then multiplying by `(long double)500` can be slightly below 1, and casting to `int` always truncates, which will produce `0` in the end.

Comment: There are many posts to SO asking "is floating point broken?"  (Most are not associated with optimization)  Consider browsing through that list of SO postings (in search box at top of page, type in the question.  Most new C++ users have an eye opening and somewhat steep learning curve about floating point math (Note: how floating point 'works' is not a unique-to-c++ issue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `-Ofast`, `-ffast-math` is enabled, which can cause some operations to be calculated in a different and faster way. In your case, `(long double)val / 500)` can be calculated as `(long double)val * (1.0L / 500))`. This can be seen in the generated assembly when you compare `-O2` and `-Ofast` for the following function:

```
long double f(long double a)
{
    return a / 500.0L;
}
```

The assembly generated with `-O2` involves `fdiv` instruction, while the assembly generated with `-Ofast` involves `fmul` instruction, see https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/58VHxb.

Next, 1/500, that is, 0.002, is not representable by `long double` exactly. Therefore, some rounding occurs and, seemingly, in your case, this rounding happens to be down. This can be checked by the following expression:

```
500.0L * (1.0L / 500.0L) < 1.0L
```

which is evaluated as `true`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zMcjxJ. So, the exact stored multiplier is 0.002 - *some very small delta*.

Finally, the result of the multiplication is 500 * (0.002 - *delta*) = 1 - *some small value*. And when this value in converted into `int`, it's truncated, therefore the result in `int` is 0.

Answer (score 3):

`-Ofast`

> Disregard strict standards compliance. `-Ofast` enables all `-O3` optimizations. It also enables optimizations that are not valid for all standard-compliant programs. It turns on `-ffast-math`, `-fallow-store-data-races` and the Fortran-specific [...]

`-ffast-math`

> Sets the options `-fno-math-errno`, `-funsafe-math-optimizations`, `-ffinite-math-only`, `-fno-rounding-math`, `-fno-signaling-nans`, `-fcx-limited-range` and `-fexcess-precision=fast`.
>
> This option causes the preprocessor macro `__FAST_MATH__` to be defined.
>
> This option is not turned on by any `-O` option besides `-Ofast` since it can result in incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions. It may, however, yield faster code for programs that do not require the guarantees of these specifications.

Conclusion: Don't use `-ffast-math` unless you are willing to get surprises like the one you've gotten now.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the shown program snippet has a 'problem', it is the wrong way to work with floating point numbers anyway.

You, more or less, ask the program if a floating point number has an 'exact value' - in this case of '1'. Ok, to be more precise - if the value is '< 1' or '>= 1' for a value which is 'around' 1 - so exactly around the dividing limit of the two answers. But as the others have already written (or can easily be found in wikipedia, ...) floating point numbers have just limited precision. So such deviations can and will happen.

So, coming to a conclusion: You should always use rounding when doing floating point to integer conversions, i.e. '(int) round (floating_point_value)'.

PS. Contrary what others maybe say or recommend - I don't see any problem with -ffast-math calculations at all. The only 'problem' would be when (bitwise) comparing the results of some program after letting it run on different computers.

I do all my (scientific) calculations with -ffast-math (actually -Ofast). But that has never been a problem so far - since I expect floating point numbers to have some rounding errors (this is true, regardless if using -ffast-math or not) - but that's all, as far as I know.  Since I typically use 64bit floating points (double) this means, the calculations are precise to around 15 to 17 decimal digits - and the last (few) of them are inflicted with these inaccuracies - still giving me lots of 'accurate' digits - say - more than 13, depending on how complicate my calculations are.